# Python prepare training data set with evenly distrubeted response variable

Tags: python, training-data

I am working on a small machine learning project.

The dataset which i use has 56 input parameters and one categorical response variable (0/1). My problem is that the response variables are not evenly distributed. Now my question I want to prepare the training data set, that the responses are evenly distributed. How can this be done?

That's how the data looks like
[image: 1]

-> the training dataset should have the same amount of 1 and 0 from the response.

Thanks for your help, as you can imagine i am really a beginner...

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

i am the same person like the one who asked the question. sorry for that.
first i load the data from a csv file.(not in the code shown here) this is stored as data, next, i create a new column named " response_class" based on the value in the column "response" if it is below .045, response_class =1, other 0. second, i randomly sample 10000 rows from the data. (due to computation limits), and here i want to make sure that i get the same amount of 1 and 0 from the response_class. at the end i split the data to make it ready for a correlation matrix and test and train data

Here is my code:

```
data = data[data.response != 0]

pd.DataFrame(data)
data['response_class'] = np.where(data['response'] <= 0.045, 1, 0)
#1=below .045  / 0=above 0.045

#reduce amount of data by picking random samples
data= data.sample(n=10000)

#split data
data.drop(['response'], axis=1, inplace=True)
y = data['response_class']
X = data.drop('response_class', axis=1)
X_names = X.columns

data.head()
```

Comment: Can you describe the code? This would add a value to your answer.

Comment: I mean edit the answer and add some explanation to it :)

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
    #seperate based on the response variable in response_class
df_zero = pd.DataFrame(data[data.response_class== 0])
df_one = pd.DataFrame(data[data.response_class == 1])

# upsampling minority class
df_zero_min = resample(df_zero,
                      replace = True,
                      n_samples = len(df_one),
                      random_state = 123)

df_upsampled = pd.concat([df_one,df_zero_min])

df_upsampled.response_class.value_counts()
```